# Correct way to publish model to delegated view?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a `UITableViewController` which provides an array of strings as data source:

```
import UIKit

class ItemsViewController: UITableViewController {

    let items = [
        "Bob",
        "Joe",
    ]

    @IBAction
    func unwindToSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Item", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel.text = items[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

}
```

I now added a second scene with a `UIViewController` which is activated when the user clicks on a `UITableCell` through a *show segue*.

I would now like to take the string assigned with the former `UITableCell` and inserted into the `ItemViewController`:

```
import UIKit

class ItemViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet
    weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        //var name = segue.someMethodHowIGetTheDataAssignedToTableCell
        //nameLabel.text = name
    }

}
```

How do I pass the model (in this case the string) assigned to the single TableCell over to the new `ItemViewController`?

Comment: Your prepareForSegue implementation should be in the table view controller, not ItemViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this.  Just add a return push segue from ItemViewController back to ItemsViewController.  Name them less similar in the future :-)

```
import UIKit

class ItemsViewController: UITableViewController {

    let items = [
        "Bob",
        "Joe",
    ]

    @IBAction
    func unwindToSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Item", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel.text = items[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

//Passing details to detail VC
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
            let theDestination = (segue.destinationViewController as ItemViewController)
            theDestination.itemName = items[indexPath!.row]
    }

}

import UIKit

class ItemViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet  weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

var itemName = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        nameLabel.text = itemName
    }

}
```

Comment: I think the OP is just asking about passing data forward to the detail controller.

Comment: Sure, I gave him that, plus full plug and play code.  I tested it and it passes the value he wants to the detail controller.